# I got IntegrityError with delete user in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-registration

When I delete user , I got this error.

```
IntegrityError at /api/user/25/
update or delete on table "profiles_customuser" violates foreign key constraint "registration_registr_user_id_5fcbf725_fk_profiles_" on table "registration_registrationprofile"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(25) is still referenced from table "registration_registrationprofile".


Request Method: DELETE
Request URL: https://dev.onepaper.biz/api/user/25/

 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
   return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (update or delete on table "profiles_customuser" violates foreign key constraint "registration_registr_user_id_5fcbf725_fk_profiles_" on table "registration_registrationprofile"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(25) is still referenced from table "registration_registrationprofile".
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
   response = get_response(request)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
   return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
   return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
   response = self.handle_exception(exc)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
   self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
   raise exc
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
   response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/onepaper-green/profiles/views.py", line 320, in destroy
   instance.delete()
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in delete
   return collector.delete()
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 435, in delete
   signals.post_delete.send(
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 232, in __exit__
   connection.commit()
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 266, in commit
   self._commit()
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
   return self.connection.commit()
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
   raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
 File "/home/ubuntu/djangovenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 242, in _commit
   return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /api/user/25/
Exception Value: update or delete on table "profiles_customuser" violates foreign key constraint "registration_registr_user_id_5fcbf725_fk_profiles_" on table "registration_registrationprofile"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(25) is still referenced from table "registration_registrationprofile".
```

There are some problems with moving django-registration-redux(django-registration) to django-allauth.
So I was trying to drop registration_registrationprofile table.
But I can't find that table.

I can only see those tables.
It isn't look like related to this problem.
How can I delete user succesfully?

```
account_emailaddress                  papers_paperstatus
account_emailconfirmation             papers_signature
addresses_address                     papers_verifyingexplanation
auth_group                            profiles_alloweduser
auth_group_permissions                profiles_alloweduser_allowed_users
auth_permission                       profiles_customuser
authtoken_token                       profiles_customuser_groups
django_admin_log                      profiles_customuser_user_permissions
django_content_type                   profiles_expertprofile
django_migrations                     profiles_mandate
django_session                        profiles_profile
django_site                           socialaccount_socialaccount
papers_contractor                     socialaccount_socialapp
papers_explanationsignature           socialaccount_socialapp_sites
papers_paper                          socialaccount_socialtoken
```

I guess It had some additional FK info when I used django-registration-redux But after moving to django-allauth, it's no more needed.
How can I delete it successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "authtoken\_token" violates foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889320/django-db-utils-integrityerror-insert-or-update-on-table-authtoken-token-viol)

Comment: I can't do this because it's product service.

Comment: The problem is that not migrate zero with django_registration_redux.

Comment: I can now delete user with django_registration_redux migrate to zero.

But there is a tiny problem. I can't rollback migration 0003 to 0002.

I got this error 

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.IrreversibleError: Operation <RunPython <function migrate_activated_status at 0x00000249AB081B80>> in registration.0003_migrate_activatedstatus is not reversible
```

So I did it --fake option now I can delete user but I don't know registration field is also delete clearly.

Comment: https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/master/registration/migrations/0001_initial.py

look into this migration code.
First if you need to solve kind of this problem, you need to know which table makes problem and when you need that table.
If you don't need that table anymore, just drop the table.
If you don't know how to do that, find the django third party app that includes migration file made that table.
And then you can python manage.py migrate app_name zero.
It makes drop all table related to that table.